# Redhat rcp_bh service maxing out cpu

Tags: linux, process, rhel

I have an redhat instance that has a process "rcp_bh" constantly running and consuming 100% of my CPU. If I kill it, it starts back up a few hours.

I can't seem to find any documentation on what it is or does.

Please I want to know whether it is a system process, and how I can manage its resource usage.

If it isn't a critical service, how do I stop it permanently.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww pointed out a more appropriate place to post this. closing the ticket.

Comment: You can flag the question and ask the moderators move it so you don't have to delete it on one site and create it on another site. It also resets the question's score. For whatever reasons, the Stack Exchange network does not allow you to migrate it yourself. Also see [Author initiated migration to other SE sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take look at this, and that's probably a bitcoing-miner-malware
https://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/bitcoing-miner-malware-linux-running-redhat-60